# PHP Not Executing the SQL Query for Updating User Details

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in the database, artists (username and password) and artistcard (contains info about the artist with one of the columns being artist_id to link to the artists table).

Now I want the users to be able to update the information displayed in the card:

Currently I get firstname, lastname, genre and location from the form that they can submit:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
   $genre    = trim($_POST['genre']);
   $location = trim($_POST['location']);
   $firstname = trim($_POST['firstname']);
   $lastname  = trim($_POST['lastname']);
   $artistcard = new Artistcard();
   $artistcard->first_name = $firstname;
   $artistcard->last_name=$lastname;
   $artistcard->genre = $genre;
   $artistcard->location = $location;
   $artistcard->artist_id = $_SESSION['artist_id'];
   $artistcard->update();
}
```

Now I want the update function to go through the fields where artist_id in the artistcard table matches id in the artist table (or session id). For this I have in the Artistcard class:

```
public function update() {
  global $database;
  $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
  $attribute_pairs = array();
  foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
    $attribute_pairs[]= "{$key}='{$value}'";
  }
  // - UPDATE table SET key='value', key='value' WHERE condition
  $sql = "UPDATE ".self::$table_name." SET ";
  $sql .= join(", ", $attribute_pairs);
  $sql .= " WHERE artist_id=". $database->escape_value($this->artist_id);
  $database->query($sql);
  return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

which returns Database Query Failed. I'm guessing the SQL is not correct? I have an almost identical **CREATE method, which works fine:**

```
public function create(){
 global $database;
 $attributes  = $this->sanitized_attributes();
 $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
 $sql .= join(",",array_keys($attributes));
 $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
 $sql .= join("', '",array_values($attributes));
 $sql .= "')";
 if ($database->query($sql)) {
 $this->id = $database->insert_id();
 return true;} else {return false;}
}
```

Comment: Which API are you using? You'll need to add some proper error-checking - you're currently just assuming that everything works fine, always. Also, you should use parameterized queries with placeholders instead of escaping.

Comment: `var($sql);` before ` $database->query($sql);` returns what?

Comment: As bassxzero said with need the content of the $sql var to assess this.

Comment: UPDATE artistcard SET id='', artist_id='9', first_name='asda', last_name='asdasd', genre='asd', location='asdasd' WHERE artist_id=9

Comment: Could you suggest how to remove this id? I don't want to make changes to the id

Comment: `SET id=''` I'm pretty sure id is your primary key, which would make this query invalid.

Comment: yes, it is. I don't want to include it as field, so I should just remove it from public variables in that class?

Comment: Entities should not know how to save themselves. You should use a data mapper. https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I'm on the right track now.